# VS 2013 project to be run on another machine having VS 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have an application written in C# (VS 2013) which is connecting to a database using MySQL. Is it possible to run this program on another computer without installing MySQL, which has VS 2010. i wish to run the application with .exe file, if that is possible?
Furthermore, the application is about collecting information about Academic/Recruitment Tests through "forms" so the information is updated in the database also.
Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right, but you can run the compiled EXE file on every system that offers the .NET version specified in your project settings.